# Browserify recipe for AngularJS + source maps + minification

Tags: angularjs, minify, gulp, browserify

I am looking for a working recipe that can minify my AngularJS code and still provide a source map. Currently I have this gulp task but minification won't work:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function(cb) {
    var bundler = browserify({
            entries: [paths.browserEntry],
            globals: false,
            debug:   !settings.PRODUCTION
        })

    bundler
        .bundle()

        .on('error', cb)
        .on('log',   util.log)

        .pipe(gulpif(!settings.PRODUCTION, mold.transformSourcesRelativeTo(paths.js)))
        .pipe(source(paths.js))
        .pipe(buffer()) // because the next steps do not support streams
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(settings.server.minify.js, rename({suffix: '.min'})))
        .pipe(gulpif(settings.server.minify.js, uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
        .on('end', function() {
            cb()
        })
})
```

Any clues?

Comment: Will you like to see an example in grunt? :-)

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Might be helpful and give some hints. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You may see an [example](https://github.com/mallim/browserify_angular_minify) here. The example will output a minified bundle.min.js plus a bundle.map. The crucial points which makes the example works:

- Installed debowerify
- Installed minifyify

**package.json** - added transform property

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  }
```

**Gruntfile.js** - using preBundleCB to make minifyify work

```
  preBundleCB: function (b) {
    b.plugin( minifyify,
      { output: './dist/bundle.map',
        map:'bundle.map'
      });
  }
```

Hope the example is useful to you.